# Numpy load large file extremely slowly when tensorflow is training

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, file

I try training 10 tasks at the same time.(each GPU one task).
I use the shell script to start 10 python processes at the same time.
When the dataset file is small, the ten tasks almost finish the loading process at the same time, and their training process are fine and fast.
When the dataset file is large(almost 70G), then some tasks may finish the loading process faster and start to train while other tasks are still in loading process. But after some tasks get into training process, the others' loading speed will be very very slowly.And the training speed also become slowly.
I use numpy to load the dataset. The dataset will be completely loaded at first and sent into the model with tf.data.dataset.

I am wandering while the tensorflow training process will conflict with the numpy load process in other tasks and how to fix it.

```py
def load_factor_file(in_file):
    try:
        key_name = os.path.basename(in_file).split('.')[0]
        factor_arr = np.load(in_file)
        return {key_name: factor_arr}
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"{str(e)}")
        return {}


def load_factor_files(in_files, store_dict):

    for f in in_files:
        fo = load_factor_file(f)
        store_dict.update(fo)
        del fo


def get_tensor_feature_label(version, txt_files, batch_size, run_mode, label_num, feature_np_dict, label_np_dict):

    def get_data_from_cache(string_message):
        feature_index, label_index, key = string_message.decode().split(',')
        feature_index = int(feature_index)
        label_index = int(label_index)
        slice_arr = feature_np_dict[key][feature_index - FACTOR_WINDOW + 1: feature_index + 1]
        label_value = label_np_dict[key][label_index]
        x_data = slice_arr.astype(np.float32)
        y_data = label_value.astype(np.float32)
        return x_data, y_data

    def parser(txt_string_in):
        feat, label = tf.numpy_function(
            get_data_from_cache, [txt_string_in], (tf.float32, tf.float32))
        feat = tf.reshape(feat, (FACTOR_WINDOW, FACTOR_NUM_MAP[version]))
        label = tf.reshape(label, (label_num,))
        return feat, label

    ds = tf.data.TextLineDataset.list_files(txt_files)
    ds = ds.apply(
        tf.data.experimental.parallel_interleave(
            tf.data.TextLineDataset,
            cycle_length=8,
            sloppy=False))

    ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=batch_size)
    ds = ds.cache()
    ds = ds.repeat()

    if run_mode == 'train':
        ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=1000)

    ds = ds.apply(
        tf.data.experimental.map_and_batch(
            map_func=parser,
            batch_size=batch_size,
            num_parallel_batches=10))
    ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=10)

    iterator = tf.data.make_one_shot_iterator(ds)
    features, labels = iterator.get_next()
    logger.info(f"feature size {features.shape}, label size {labels.shape}")
    return features, labels


def main(not_use_args):
    if FLAGS.use_hvd != 0:
        import horovod.tensorflow as hvd
        hvd.init()

    txt_path = f"{ARR_DATA_PATH_MAP[FLAGS.version]}/{FLAGS.stock}/{FLAGS.run_mode}/txt"

    batch_size = FLAGS.batch_size
    # model configeration
    configuration = get_config(
        txt_path, batch_size,
        FLAGS.config_name, FLAGS.use_hvd, FLAGS.stock,
        FLAGS.run_mode, FLAGS.max_per_epoch)
    configuration['fn_params']["lr"] = FLAGS.lr
    configuration['fn_params']["lr_decay_type"] = FLAGS.lr_decay_type
    configuration['fn_params']['use_hvd'] = FLAGS.use_hvd

    max_steps = FLAGS.epoch * configuration["fn_params"]["steps_per_epoch"]
    configuration["fn_params"]["max_steps"] = max_steps
    if FLAGS.warm_up_epochs > 0:
        configuration["fn_params"]["warm_up_epochs"] = FLAGS.warm_up_epochs

    configuration['model_dir'] = get_model_dir(configuration['model_dir'], configuration['name'])
    configuration["fn_params"]["optimizer"] = FLAGS.optimizer

    if FLAGS.train_scope != "None":
        configuration["fn_params"]["train_scope"] = FLAGS.train_scope

    t0_regression = create_estimator(configuration, FLAGS.threads)

    # load np data
    factor_files = glob.glob(f"{ARR_DATA_PATH_MAP[FLAGS.version]}/{FLAGS.stock}/{FLAGS.run_mode}/factor/{txt_round}-*.npy")
    label_files = glob.glob(f"{ARR_DATA_PATH_MAP[FLAGS.version]}/{FLAGS.stock}/{FLAGS.run_mode}/label/{txt_round}-*.npy")
    txt_files = glob.glob(f"{txt_path}/{txt_round}-*.txt")

    logger.info(f"Loading factors = {factor_files}, label = {label_files}")
        

    input_fn = functools.partial(
        get_tensor_feature_label,
        version=FLAGS.version,
        txt_files=txt_files,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        run_mode=FLAGS.run_mode,
        label_num=label_num,
        feature_np_dict=feature_np_dict,
        label_np_dict=label_np_dict)

    log_dir = configuration["model_dir"] + '/tf_logs'

    logging_hooks = get_log_hooks(
        log_dir=log_dir,
        save_steps=configuration["fn_params"]["steps_per_epoch"],
        run_mode=FLAGS.run_mode,
        test_total_num=FLAGS.test_total_num
    )

    
    all_hooks = logging_hooks

    t0_regression.train(
        input_fn=input_fn,
        max_steps=max_steps,
        hooks=all_hooks)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

Comment: Maybe you're loading the arrays inefficiently? Can you post your code?

Comment: Update your question with your code. Not add a comment. And please include enough code that it can be replicated. Showing a function of a few lines doesn't say anything.

Comment: The code has been added.

Comment: Why you are loading the data at all, another way is to load the data on-demand! I mean you can use `tf.data.Dataset.from_list()` and then further you can use `ds.map()` a *numpy function* which will load the data as training starts. it will not load all the data from the disk only one batch and when one batch is executed, another batch will be fetched before executing the next batch.

Comment: Cause the data is stock tick data. If I load data from the disk, I have to split the raw tick data in one day to several samples. On the one hand, it will cost too much hard disk space. On the other hand, the speed load from disk is slower than the memory.